# Why do I sometimes get error 5 with an Instr function?

Tags: vba, outlook

```
aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1)
```

I have a script that changes the body of an email. I want to delete everything after the "-" caracter in a specific string.

The code works great but sometimes I get this error 5 on this line.

Why does the error happens only a few times even though the body of the email is correct and isn't supposed to produce errors ? Thank You.

```
Option Explicit


     Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
                Private Sub Application_Startup()
                Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
                Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
                Set olApp = Outlook.Application
                Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
                ' default local Inbox
                Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test").Items
                End Sub
                Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

                 Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
                 If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
                Set Msg = item
                ' ******************
    Dim patternRef As String
    Dim patternDemandeur As String
    Dim patternNumero As String
    Dim patternDescriptionPanne As String
    Dim patternAdresse As String
    Dim patternDomaine As String
    Dim patternStatut As String
    Dim patternMotifDemande As String


    item.UnRead = False

    patternRef = "Numéro de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternDemandeur = "Emetteur[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternNumero = "N° tel de l'émetteur de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternDescriptionPanne = "Commentaires initial[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternAdresse = "Localisation de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternDomaine = "Famille motif[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternStatut = "Statut[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"
    patternMotifDemande = "Motif de la demande[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"


' Creation des differentes variables récuperées dans l'émail de base        
    Dim sText As String 'Variable qui reprendra le corps de l'émail reçu.
    Dim xText As String 'Variable reférence de la demande.
    Dim yText As String 'Variable reférence du demandeur.
    Dim zText As String 'Variable reférence du numero de telephone.
    Dim dText As String 'Variable reférence de la description de la panne.
    Dim aText As String 'Variable reférence de l'adresse.
    Dim bText As String 'Variable reférence du domaine d'intervention.
    Dim cText As String 'Variable reférence du statut fournit par l'entreprise.
    Dim oText As String 'Variable reférence du motif de la demande.




    sText = Msg.Body ' affectation de la variable





    xText = TestRegExp(sText, patternRef, 0)
    yText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDemandeur, 0)
    zText = TestRegExp(sText, patternNumero, 0)
    dText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDescriptionPanne, 0)
    aText = TestRegExp(sText, patternAdresse, 0)
    aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1) 'Permet de supprimer tout les charactères après le tiret. Garde dans le aText, du premier charactere au tiret -1 donc sans le tiret.
    oText = TestRegExp(sText, patternMotifDemande, 0)
    bText = TestRegExp(sText, patternDomaine, 1)
    cText = TestRegExp(sText, patternStatut, 0)



  Dim NewMail As MailItem ' nouvel email
    Dim obApp As Object
    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'ces 3 lignes creent le mail.



    With NewMail 'remplissage du mail
        .Subject = "Domain"

        .To = "email"

        .Body = "REF=" & xText & vbCrLf & "DOM=" & bText & vbCrLf & "OBJ=" & aText & vbCrLf & "DEMANDE D'INTERVENTION : " & oText & vbCrLf & dText & vbCrLf & "Appelant : " & yText & " / " & zText

        .Importance = olImportanceHigh



    End With


    NewMail.Send
                End If


                End Sub









Function TestRegExp(myString As String, pattern As String, casDomaine As Integer)

'Create objects.
    Dim objRegExp As RegExp
    Dim objMatch As Match
    Dim colMatches  As MatchCollection
    Dim RetStr As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim resultPrep As String


' Create a regular expression object.
    Set objRegExp = New RegExp

'Set the pattern by  the Pattern property.
    objRegExp.pattern = pattern

' Set Case Insensitivity.
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

'Set global applicability.
    objRegExp.Global = True

'Test whether the String can be compared.
    If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

'Get the matches.
        Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.



        If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

'Get the matches.
            Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.

            For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.

                If casDomaine = 0 Then

                    result = objMatch.SubMatches(0)

                End If


                If casDomaine = 1 Then

'Idealement ne demander que si le texte contient un mot clé pour éviter les erreurs de typo. Resolu par utilisation de conditions, à tester avec Case

' Select Case objMatch.SubMatches(0)

                    If trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Faible")) Then
' "Electricité (C.Faible)"

                        result = "28"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Fort")) Then
'  "Electricité (C.Fort)"

                        result = "27"

                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Plomberie")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Sanitaire")) Then
' "Plomberie / Sanitaire" / essayer d'eviter de lancer 2 cases (FaT)
                        result = "30"


                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Clim")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Chauf")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Ventil")) Then
' "Clim / Chauf / Ventil"
                        result = "24"


                    ElseIf trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Sécurité")) Or trouverMotDomaine(LCase(objMatch.SubMatches(0)), LCase("Incendie")) Then
' "Sécurité / Incendie"
                        result = "32"

                    Else
                        result = "3"
                    End If


                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

    TestRegExp = result

 'Affichage de chaque resultat pour la phase test

    ' MsgBox result // Affiche resultat à chaque fois pour les phases de test.



End Function


Function trouverMotDomaine(domaine As String, motCle As String) As Boolean

    Dim intPos As Integer

    intPos = 0
    intPos = InStr(domaine, motCle)
    trouverMotDomaine = intPos > 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get `Runtime Error 5` error if `aText` does not have "-" and hence you should rewrite your code to

```
If InStr(1, aText, "-") Then
    aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1)
End If
```

**Edit**

```
If InStr(1, aText, Chr(45)) Then
    aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, Chr(45)) - 1)
    MsgBox "Found a Dash"
ElseIf InStr(1, aText, Chr(151)) Then
    aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, Chr(151)) - 1)
    MsgBox "Found a Hyphen"
End If
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the strange thing is that the "-" is always there and when I relaunch the code by sending again the same email, the code works proprely. I'm gonna change the code anyway to what You suggested.

Comment: If you feel `aText` will always have "-" then debug the code and check what is the value of `aText` at runtime. Also ensure that you are correctly storing the value in `aText` i.e you are using proper objects and not something like `Selection.text`

Comment: I debuged the code and the value of aText is correct. I think there might be a problem with the format of the body when it's sent. When I transfer the mail to myself in order to relaunch the script, it works great whereas when it's someone else it doesn't and comes with this error. In both cases the body is the same.

Comment: Can I send it to You in private ? Thank You very much for Your time

Comment: Unfortunatley no.It is not conducive for the learning of others. I hope you do not mind?

Comment: No it's ok I've deleted confidentials informations, thank You again.

Comment: lol you again posted it as an answer... You need to edit the question and post it there. Anyways, I have copied to code. Let me check it

Comment: Damn sorry haha

Comment: Just after the line `aText = TestRegExp(sText, patternAdresse, 0)`, if you type `Msgbox InStr(1, aText, "-")` then what do you get?

Comment: Also see my edit. can you replace `aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1)` with the code that I posted and tell me what messagebox do you get. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: I did what you asked and i get 0 in the msgbox.

Comment: I got "Found a dash"

Comment: Just as I thought :) you are checking for a `Hyphen (-)` whereas the body has a `Dash (—)` ;)

Comment: Oh haha thank you very much. Yet why does it work sometimes? Thank you again

Comment: Formatting issues I guess :)

Comment: Okay thanks, so I should always check for  a dash or both to  make it more secure?

Comment: Check for both to make it more secure.

Comment: Okay thanks, how could I resolve the problems with formatting issues ? Should i auto transfer the mail to myself and then launch the script ? It seems that it always work when i retransfer mannually the mail to myself.

Comment: not needed. simply check for the dash forst and then check for the hyphen

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it does not find `-` in the `aText` string, and thus the `Left()` formula fails. Try this check, before doing the `Left()`:

```
If InStr(1, aText, "-") > 0 Then aText = Left(aText, InStr(1, aText, "-") - 1)
```